# How to get just selected value from the group of elements with the same name?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

I have two radio buttons with the same name but different values. I have to check before I submit my form that value selected id correct otherwise give message to user.

Here is my HTML code:

```
<td>
 <label>
   <span><input type="radio" name="directed" value="1" id="directed_yes"></span>
   <span>Yes</span>
 </label><br>
 <label>
   <span><input type="radio" name="directed" value="0" id="directed_no"></span>
   <span>No</span>
 </label>
</td>
```

Here is my JQuery that i tried to use:

```
var directed = $('input[name=directed]').each(function(){
  alert($(this).val())
});
```

This code gave me all values for elements with the same name, I just need selected value. After that I have to check if that value is valid before submitting the form. If anyone know how to get just selected value please let me know. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can just use the `:checked` selector and `val()`: like this:

```
var directed = $('input[name=directed]:checked').val();
```

```js
$('button').click(function() {
    var directed = $('input[name=directed]:checked').val();
    alert(directed);
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label>
    <span><input type="radio" name="directed" value="1" id="directed_yes"></span>
    <span>Yes</span>
</label>
<br>
<label>
    <span><input type="radio" name="directed" value="0" id="directed_no"></span>
    <span>No</span>
</label>

<br /><br />
<button>Get value</button>
```

Comment: That's exactly what I was looking for. Without ':checked' I was getting same value no matter what was checked. Thanks a lot!

Comment: No problem, glad to help.